# How to make a classfication attribute as searchble in hybris?

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

I have created a classification class and classification attribute and linked to some products in features. I even added that attribute to solrindexedproperty. But the OOTB solr search not providing any results for my attribute. How to make my classification attribute searchable using solr.

Comment: have you checked in your solr server http://localhost:8983/solr/ whether products are actually indexed with your classification attributes ?

Answer (score 1):

Please use CommerceClassificationPropertyValueProvider.
Here is example Impex snippet.

```
# Define macros needed to select proper classification system
$classificationCatalog=trainingClassification
$classSystemVersion=systemVersion(catalog(id[default='$classificationCatalog']),version[default='1.0'])
$classCatalogVersion=catalogVersion(catalog(id[default='$classificationCatalog']),version[default='1.0'])
$classAttribute=classificationAttribute(code,$classSystemVersion)
$classClass=classificationClass(code,$classCatalogVersion)
$classAttributeAssignment=classAttributeAssignment($classClass,$classAttribute,$classSystemVersion)

INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexedProperty;solrIndexedType(identifier)[unique=true];name[unique=true];type(code);sortableType(code);currency[default=false];localized[default=false];multiValue[default=false];facet[default=false];facetType(code);facetSort(code);priority;fieldValueProvider;customFacetSortProvider;rangeSets(name);$classAttributeAssignment
#;$solrIndexedType;CLASSIFICATION_ATTRIBUTE_CODE;SOLR_INDEXED_PROPERTY_TYPE;;;;;true;FACET_TYPE;FACET_SORT;PRIORITY;commerceClassificationPropertyValueProvider;;SOLR_RANGE;CLASSIFICATION_CLASS_CODE:::CLASSIFICATION_ATTRIBUTE_CODE::::
;$solrIndexedType;puzzlePieces;string;;;;;true;Refine;Alpha;1000;commerceClassificationPropertyValueProvider;;;puzzles:::puzzlePieces::::
;$solrIndexedType;puzzlePieceSize;string;;;;;true;Refine;Alpha;900;commerceClassificationPropertyValueProvider;;;puzzles:::puzzlePieceSize::::
```